# Can a non-zero matrix in row echelon form multiplied by itself be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a Matrix $A$, presume that $A^2 =0$ then the row echelon form of $A$ has no leading ones. True or False.

I think it is true but I do not know how to go about showing it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following matrix is in row echelon form:
$$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$
yet $A^2=0$.